# My useReducer hook does not update the state for only one dispatch type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Reducer code

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add':
      return {selectedArr: initialState.selectedArr.push(action.payload)};
    case 'all':
      return {all: !initialState.all};
    case 'remove':
      return {
        selectedArr: initialState.selectedArr.splice(
          initialState.selectedArr.indexOf(action.payload),
          1,
        ),
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

Action dispatch

```
<TouchableRipple
  onPress={() => dispatch({type: 'all'})}
  rippleColor={Theme.colors.accent}
>
  <Surface style={[styles.ptpListFilterSurface]}>
    <Text>All</Text>
  </Surface>
</TouchableRipple>
```

Can someone help me with why just this dispatch does not work? The other dispatches work perfectly

Comment: Few problems: you refer to the initialState instate of current state which is given to you as a parameter, and the most problematic thing (conceptually) is that you used `push` and `splice` which cause the array mutation. Since arrays are basically objects, mutating them will not change their reference, hence react "does not see" the state change (as it didn't, the reference is the same) and therfore the state wouldn't update

Comment: But all the other dispatches except the case 'all' does work, hence the question that why only the case 'all' does not update the state.

Comment: My answer stays the same, you should change the code anyways :) and about all, it's probably because you refer to `initialState`.

Comment: I used initialState and the other dispatches work fine